# Hide subfolder for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so my subdomain currently goes to the same root folder as my domain. I would like to accomplish the following:

```
sub.domain.com => sub.domain.com/sub/
```

with the /sub/ portion invisible to the user.

I do not want to have the following happen:

```
sub.domain.com => domain.com/sub/
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this without redirection and without getting stuck in an endless loop? I have this currently and I don't think it's working as it doesn't mask the /sub part:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub
RewriteRule .* http://sub.domain.com/sub[L]
```

I've looked endlessly online for something that accomplishes this but can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out through a bunch of trial and error:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [L]
```